# Delete Rows that have a Specific Value in a Specific Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with a Macro I'm try to do.

I want to delete the rows if in `Range("D5",Range("D5").End(xlDown))` finds certain values doesn't match but when I run the code, it misses some values.

This is my code so far:

```
Dim Codex As Range
Set Codex = Worksheets("Centerlines Tracking").Range("D5", Range("D5").End(xlDown))

For Each Cell In Codex
    If Cell.Value = "AD001" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD002" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD015" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD031" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD005" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD035" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD100" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD107" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD108" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD152" _
    Or Cell.Value = "AD173" _
    Or Cell.Value = "CO017" _
    Or Cell.Value = "CO081" _
    Or Cell.Value = "CO102" _
    Or Cell.Value = "CO035" _
    Or Cell.Value = "CO169" _
    Or Cell.Value = "CR003" Then

    Else
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: When deleting rows you need to start from the bottom, otherwise you will skip.  `For i = LastRow to 2 Step -1` for instance where LastRow of the data is defined as `Long`.  You can search on ways to find the last row of a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must loop backwards when deleting rows as otherwise you might skip rows. Hence, you also have to switch to a counter in your loop.

```
Sub x()

Dim Codex As Range, i As Long

Set Codex = Worksheets("Centerlines Tracking").Range("D5", Range("D5").End(xlDown))

For i = Codex.Count To 1 Step -1
    Select Case Codex.Cells(i)
        Case "AD001", "AD002", "AD015", "AD031", "AD005", "AD035", "AD100", "AD107", "AD108", _
             "AD152", "AD173", "CO017", "CO081", "CO102", "CO035", "CO169", "CR003"
            'do nothing
        Case Else
            Codex.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End Select
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. I was also searching how to use some kind of array and not add only `OR` and avoid the macros run so slow. Thank you very much!

Comment: `Select case` isn't any quicker than `If`, just easier tor ead sometimes. Using arrays would be quicker but unless you have a lot of data it's unlikely to make a big difference.

Comment: Well, this macro is being used for more than 2,000 rows and growing. I need to add 66 codes to that `case`. Anyways, it helped me a lot. Thank you

Comment: Another way might be store your codes in a named range and then reference that rather than having a very long list of exclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Plus a Select Case Statement:

```
testvalue = VBA.Trim(Cell.Value) '' use trim() to normalize the input
''debug.print(testvalue) ''enable this line to see what is happening in debug

Select Case True

   Case instr(testvalue, "CR003", 1, vbTextCompare) ''use vbTextCompare to ignore caps/lower
   ''do stuff like delete or w/e
   Case instr(testvalue, "CR004", 1, vbTextCompare)

   Case Else
   ''do nothing or put a goto next: label
End Select
```